# Problems with writing to HID InputDevice (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hid

[(A shameful copy-paste of this)](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1947689/problems-with-writing-to-hid-inputdevice.html)
I'm currently developing a system that revolves around connecting to a HID Device. I've correctly set up the device to be a recognised InputDevice in Unity, fit with the IInputStateTypeInfo etc.. However, I'm running into a problem when it comes to sending over a command to the device using **ExecuteCommand()**. I'm trying to send over an array of 33 bytes, with the second one being the letter 'C' represented as a byte, and the following 3 bytes representing R, G, and B values (with the rest being 0s).

An example of what I'm sending over:

00 53 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I'm able to also use the HIDAPI Library to send over the bytes using DeviceIoControl. However, using hid_write fails due to an overlapping I/O error, if that's relevant or not.

I may be able to fall back onto using DevicoIoControl if it's also possible to obtain the HID device path of an InputDevice or some other representation of it

Here is my code for the command:

```csharp
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = kSize)]
 struct SetColorCommand : IInputDeviceCommandInfo
 {
     public static FourCC Type => new FourCC('H', 'I', 'D', 'O');
     internal const int kSize = InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize + 33;
     [FieldOffset(0)]
     public InputDeviceCommand baseCommand;
     [FieldOffset(InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize)]
     public byte reportID;
     [FieldOffset(InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize + 1)]
     public byte command; // The command code 'C'
     [FieldOffset(InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize + 2)]
     public byte red; // The red value
     [FieldOffset(InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize + 3)]
     public byte green; // The green value
     [FieldOffset(InputDeviceCommand.BaseCommandSize + 4)]
     public byte blue; // The blue value
     public FourCC typeStatic => Type;
     public static SetColorCommand Create(byte r, byte g, byte b)
     {
         return new SetColorCommand
         {
             baseCommand = new InputDeviceCommand(Type, kSize),
             command = Convert.ToByte('C'),
             red = r,
             green = g,
             blue = b
         };
     }
 }
```

Maybe it's some problem with my device?

I've been looking around virtually everywhere to piece together how to create this command and to create multiple iterations, but my implementation still fails to work. My current code implementation doesn't send over the 33 bytes I'd like it to. The command doesn't give out any exceptions, it just fails